# GraphQL parser returns unknown field error for known field

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs

I'm building a new `createRefetchContainer()` off a working implementation in the same project, but getting this error on running `yarn relay`:

```
ERROR:
GraphQLParser: Unknown field `usersByName` on type `Viewer`. 
Source: document `AutocompleteUsersContainer_UsersRefetchQuery` file:
 `client/components/Autocomplete/Users/AutocompleteUsersContainer.js`.
```

The erroring relay function:

```
export default createRefetchContainer(
  AutocompleteUsers,
  graphql`
    fragment AutocompleteUsersContainer_viewer on Viewer
      @argumentDefinitions(name: { type: "String", defaultValue: "" }) {
      usersByName(name: $name)
    }
  `,
  graphql`
    query AutocompleteUsersContainer_UsersRefetchQuery(
      $name: String!
    ) {
      viewer {
        usersByName(name: $name){
          id
        }
      }
    }
  `
);
```

The working implementation:

```
export default createRefetchContainer(
  AutocompleteLocations,
  graphql`
    fragment AutocompleteLocationsContainer_viewer on Viewer
      @argumentDefinitions(searchValue: { type: "String", defaultValue: "" }) {
      locations(searchValue: $searchValue)
    }
  `,
  graphql`
    query AutocompleteLocationsContainer_LocationsRefetchQuery(
      $searchValue: String!
    ) {
      viewer {
        locations(searchValue: $searchValue)
      }
    }
  `
);
```

The `usersByName` query below returns results directly in graphql, which is why I'm not sure why `relay` says `Unknown field 'usersByname'`:

```
query getViewer{
  viewer {
    usersByName(
      name: "Test Name"
    ) {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your schema updated and have your or do you need to run `relay-compiler`?

Comment: Just figured it out now, yep the schema needed to be updated. Fixed with `yarn schema`

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by running `yarn schema` before `yarn relay`